# Durandal Compose: activate method not always called

Tags: binding, single-page-application, durandal, activation

In a SPA,I have a view in which I include another view using the compose binding. This sub view (child view) has an activate method which is called when the parent view is loaded.

```
<div data-bind="compose: 'viewmodel/fol/index'"></div>
```

However, when I navigate away from the parent view and then go back to it (without refreshing the browser), the activate method in the child view is not longer called. How can I force this to be called each time the parent view is loaded?

Comment: really good question btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not leveraging the router here, the behavior of the child viewModel will not respect the full activation lifecycle. There are two approaches you can take: (a) leverage the router or (b) manually activate the child.

If you wanted to take the first approach, you would create a child router on the viewModel and create a `router` binding instead of a `compose` binding. That might be overkill in this case so I will skip it.

The better approach, given the information you've provided here, would be to not try to hook into the activation lifecycle automatically. So instead of calling your `activate()` function activate, call it `init()`:

```
function folIndexViewModel() {

  this.init = function() {
    ...
  };
}
```

In your parent, have your activate function call init

```
var child = require('viewmodel/fol/index');
function parentViewModel() {

    this.activate = function() { 
        child.init();
    }
}
```

Note that this approach only works if your child is a singleton. More information on that at the bottom of this article: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Module.html.